# Assert that a webelement is not present - fast solution?

Tags: java, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

I need to assert that a webelement does not exist several times in my test. I have already searched for this on the site, and in the answers, found what I already have in my code:

```
try{
    WebElement w = driver.findElement(By.id("warning"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

I was wondering if there is a faster way? Because every time this runs when the element doesn't exist, it takes a long time for the exception to be caught. I know this is because the webdriver is searching the entire page for the element, but still... any faster ways?

Is it possible to somehow use WebDriverWait with a very low timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is due to implicit wait in WebDriver. To avoid this waiting while element not found you need to set the implicit wait time to zero before verifying your condition.

- Setting implicity_wait to 0 so that WebDriver does not implicitly
  wait.
- Returning True when the element is found. Catching the
  NoSuchElementException and returning False when we discover that the
  element is not present instead of stopping the test with an
  exception.
- Setting implicitly_wait back to 10 after the action is
  complete so that WebDriver will implicitly wait in future.

See [this](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/07/iselementpresent.html) for implementation of above described process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but its actually slowed down the test. 
After trying the above, it still took a long time to catch the exception. Also, a later part of the test, which usually runs fast, ran slower. Would an explicit wait work better here?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to find a list of elements, and then check the length of the list.

```
List<WebElement> warnings = driver.findElements(By.id("warning"));
if warnings.length() == 0 {
    return true;
} else return false;
```

This has the advantage on not having to wait for the timeout specified in your `driver`. Hopefully a possible alternative for you.

Comment: you can make it shorter by return warnings.length() == 0, However, it will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
boolean isElementExists(By elementSelector) {
      return driver.findElements(elementSelector).size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: It will also wait for a number of seconds set by  implicity_wait()

Answer (score 0):

Change driver implicit wait to Duration instead of Timeout, so if your implicitwait is Duration.ofSeconds(20), then if element found in 2 secs it will pick or it will fail after 20 secs.